# how to write more than 8000 chars in text column in trigger (sql2k)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2000

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_SAMPLE INSTEAD OF 
DECLARE @ptrval varbinary(16)
DECLARE @value1 varchar(8000)
DECLARE @value2 varchar(8000)
DECLARE @id int

SELECT @id = id from inserted

Select @ptrval = TEXTPTR(columnname) from tablename where id=@id
WRITETEXT table.columnname @ptrval @value1+@value2
```

gives error :

> incorrect sytax near '+'

Comment: Don't do `SELECT @var = col from inserted` - this is always broken for multi-row inserts.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it as a 2 step process.

```
WRITETEXT table.columnname @ptrval @value1
UPDATETEXT table.columnname @ptrval NULL 0 @value2
```